# How to pass hindi text using sendkeys in appium

Tags: android, automation, appium

I doing an automation and I need to pass the Hindi text using sendkeys. Softkeyboard is English on my Android phone. Below is the code. Please help.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@resource-id,'menuitem_search')]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'com.whatsapp:id/search_src_text')]")).sendKeys("आचार्य");
```